# Magento 2 want to add itemprop="image" tag in image field

Tags: image, product-view, magento2.1.0

I want to add `itemprop="image"` to main image on product page. How can I achieve this.

[image]

Comment: see image.phtml file file path:- vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image.phtml

Comment: @MagikVishal thanks for your response but it is not coming through there.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Where exactly did you place the code in view/gallery.phtml file? Before the last < /div >? and do you overwrite the original gallery.phtml file located in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml ---
or
--- vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
<?php
        $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')
            ->init($block->getProduct(), 'product_page_image_large')
            ->setImageFile($block->getImageFile())
            ->getUrl();
    ?>
    <meta itemprop="image" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $imageUrl; ?>" >
```

To:
`app/design/frontend/<vendor>/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

Comment: Thanks, It's working